# Staging stores for beta testing native apps

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store, beta-testing

I have been hacking around with both Android and iOS development for about a month now, and have successfully setup both my iPhone as well as my Samsung Galaxy to be test devices, and I have deployed apps to those phones, directly from the respective IDEs, meaning:

- I've successfully deployed a toy Swift app to my iPhone via Xcode; and
- I've successfully deployed a toy Android app to my Samsung via Android Studio

So far so good.

I'm looking to take these deployments one step further, but **not** "production" (live and available to the public in their respective stores).

I'm wondering if Apple/Google have "*staging stores*" where I can vet out my deployment pipeline and perhaps upload/deploy these apps to some store where only I (and perhaps a handful of beta testers) have access. Either that, or perhaps there is a way to limit access/visibility to apps inside of their stores before the apps are ready for full bore release.

I'm looking for a solution that would work not only for my first release (v1) but also any subsequent v2, v3, etc. releases as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment on Apple. But Google Play has Alpha and Beta publishing which lets you publish an app to a limited Group of users you choose. It sounds like Alpha is what you want.

All the details are on [this help documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213)

Furthermore, an Alpha app won't be visible to anyone besides Alpha users until you do a public, production release.